# QTabWidget tabs shelf as eclipse

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtabwidget

I am trying to achieve tabs shelf when the number of max tabs is increasing.

For Example:

Max_Tabs = 5

if number of open tabs is getting greater than 5 then the oldest one should popout to the shelf.

Can I use setcornerwidget for this?
If yes then which widget I should Consider using?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Similar to following picture:
[image]

Comment: What is a "tabs shelf"?  What do you mean "popout to the shelf"?  The corner widget is usually used for setting a "New Tab Button" or something similar.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I have included Image please have a look and give suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `setCornerWidget` for this.  You'll probably want to use a `QToolButton` with a `QMenu` for the widget.